# Puppeteer nodejs close page

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Is there a way to close a tab in puppeteer? Or do tabs automatically close when there is no reference to it (i.e., similar to garbage collector)?

My code's structure:

```
//main
let browser = await puppeteer.launch()
let res1 = await func1(browser);
let res2 = await func1(browser);

function func1(browser) {
    browser.newPage();
    ...
    //I'm not closing the page
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecloseoptions

Answer (score 11):

There's a way to close a page:

```
page.close();
```

You can read about details in the docs for the API:
https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api/puppeteer.page.close.md

was https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#pagecloseoptions

Answer (score 3):

```
await page.close();
```

Close function is **asynchronous**. That's why if you run multiple instances of Puppeteer, you should add **await**